# No Provider for InjectionToken in embedding ngx-monaco-editor

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

I'm trying to embed Monaco Editor to a web application I'm working on using this guide https://github.com/atularen/ngx-monaco-editor#readme. I tried adding the `ngx-monaco-editor` tag and Angular gives me this error. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(EditorModule)[InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG -> InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG -> InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG -> InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(EditorModule)[InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG -> InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG -> InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG -> InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:915)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11082)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11082)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11082)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:24199)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11082)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:24199)
    at Object.get (core.js:22102)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3921)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:13753)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27425)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

This is my **component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-editor',
  templateUrl: './text-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-editor.component.scss']
})
export class TextEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  editorOptions = {theme: 'vs-dark', language: 'javascript'};
  code: string= 'function x() {\nconsole.log("Hello world!");\n}';

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I already solved the glob directory issues by installing v9.0.0 but this error really got me stuck for quite sometime now.

**EDIT** Resolved by adding .forRoot to AppModule Import. My Bad! I thought I already added it

Comment: Did you add `MonacoEditorModule.forRoot() ` in AppModule?

Comment: Oh! I actually forgot to add.forRoot(). Thank you!

Comment: I had added MonacoEditorModule.forRoot(config) in my higher module, but saw this error until I added it to the app.module.ts. I didn't have to do this in a simple app I started from start.

Comment: I have Angular 17 and there is no AppModule. What is solution in this case?

Comment: @denis in app.config.ts add  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(MonacoEditorModule.forRoot({
      // ... config
    }))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure `MonacoEditorModule.forRoot()` is in your AppModule.